# insert_iterator VS back_insert_iterator

Tags: c++

I am now learning C++ STL iterator, and there's the code snippet which teaches back_insert_iterator :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
vector<int> original;

//vector<int> original = {100, 99, 98}; /* Initially empty */

/* Create a back_insert_iterator that inserts values into myVector. */

back_insert_iterator< vector<int> > itr(original);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    *itr = i + 1; // "Write" to the back_insert_iterator, appending the value.
    ++itr; }
vector<int> destination;

reverse_copy(original.begin(), original.end(),
             back_insert_iterator< vector<int> >(destination));

reverse_copy(original.begin(), original.end(),
             insert_iterator< vector<int> >(destination));

/* Print the vector contents; this displays 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 */ copy(destination.begin(), destination.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));

cout << endl;
```

Then I want to change the back_insert_iterator to insert_iterator and see what will happen, so I replaced this line of code:

```
reverse_copy(original.begin(), original.end(),
             back_insert_iterator< vector<int> >(destination));
```

with the following code:

```
reverse_copy(original.begin(), original.end(),
             insert_iterator< vector<int> >(destination));
```

However, my IDE reported that " no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'vector' to 'insert_iterator< vector >'

I couldn't understand why this happens as I think that insert_iterator should be a "father-like" iterator of back_insert_iterator, if back_insert_iterator can be applied, then insert_iterator can be applied similarly?

Comment: see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/insert_iterator/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterator adapter `insert_iterator` has only the following constructor

```
insert_iterator(Container& x, typename Container::iterator i);
```

As you see it has two parameters and the second parameter sets the position in the container where new elements will be inserted.

So you have to write

```
reverse_copy(original.begin(), original.end(),
             insert_iterator< vector<int> >(destination, destination.end()));
```

The assignment operator of the iterator adapter

```
insert_iterator<Container>&
operator=(const typename Container::value_type& value);
```

performs the following action

```
iter = container->insert(iter, value);
++iter;
```

that is it uses container's method `insert` that in turn has two parameters.

The difference compared with iterators `front_insert_iterator` and `back_insert_iterator` is that for these two iterator adapters the position where new elements will be inserted is known while for the iterator adapter `insert_iterator` you have to specify the position of the insertion yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The format of insert_iterator should be specifying both the container and the container's begin iterator as parameters as follows: `reverse_copy(original.begin(), original.end(),
                 insert_iterator< vector<int> >(destination, destination.begin()));`